# Queries running fast most of the time but >100x slower other times

Tags: performance, sql-server-2016, query-performance

I know this is a very generic question, but if someone can point me to what else I should investigate/check I would greatly appreciate it.

We have a view which runs around 15 seconds most of the time but during random times starts running around 45 minutes. These long running episodes last for hours and all of a sudden out of now where go back to running normal times.
We using SQL SERVER 2016. We have one dedicated hard drive for data, one for log and one for backup.

I have confirmed the following during the long running episodes:

1) There are no transactions open

2) There are no other heavy queries running. Used the query below:

```
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
    req.session_id,
    req.status,
    req.command,
    req.cpu_time,
    req.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```

3) There are no backups running and anti-virus does not scan the database files

4) Execution plans between the normal and the long runs are exactly the same (at least the execution plan of the top level view. The top level view unions some child views)

I am in no way a database administrator and getting one is not one of the available options.

I am wondering else could be causing these issues and what kind of queries I can run to determine the culprit. If there is anything else you would like to know please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: [Start with these steps](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/)

Comment: How is the view created - with or without schemabinding ? Can you run sp_refreshview and test ? Also, any blocking that you are encountering ?

Comment: Provide the view, and any other views or code it depends on, and the query using the view that has variable times.  My first two guesses are the usual, parameter sniffing and/or statistics being out of date and then updating.  Also, try using Live Query Statistics when it's fast as well as when it's slow.  Ideally it'll return actual live results, though that's hit and miss.  If not, it'll return the actual execution plan at the end anyway, generally.

Comment: Thank you @LowlyDBA  for those scripts. Next time we have a bottleneck, I plan on running those.

Comment: @Kin: all the views it is using is without schemabinding and I can try to run sp_refreshview next time we have bottleneck. What do you mean any blocking?